# EazyBI Issues created by Dayname

Tags: jira, mdx

i have a problem with EazyBI MDX. First of all, i am very new to EazyBI and Jira.
I need to create a Member which sums up all the Issues created on a Saturday. Hope someone can help me.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

It is quite easy but you should read EazyBI documentation first. Your question sound like "what is eazybi?".

My advice, have a look to the following resources:
https://docs.eazybi.com/display/EAZYBI/Getting+Started https://docs.eazybi.com/display/EAZYBI/MDX+Function+Reference

Regarding to your question you don't need to create a new member. Simply use Time dimension and issue dimension.  Check Time dimension using the herarchy section to choose the days that you need (you can remove other days of the week). In the issues dimension you can select created ones.
Measure dimension would be useful also.

I hope this will help you to build this report and other reports in the future.
Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to create a calculated member under [Time] dimension like below and name it like `[Time].[Saturday]`:

> ```
> Aggregate(Filter(
>   [Time].[Day].Members,
>   [Time].CurrentMember.Get('Week day name') MATCHES 'Saturday'
>   ))
> ```

Then put `[Time]` dimension into `Rows`, choose the calculated member `[Time].[Saturday]`(unselect default `All Times` members). In `Columns`, make sure you select `[Measures].[Issues created]`(this is default selection). Then you have the sums up.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way. Use the *Week day* dimension to see the distribution across weekdays. See the eazyBI Demo account for an example - https://eazybi.com/accounts/1000/cubes/Issues/reports/499773-most-active-days-by-weeks-and-weekdays.